# Can you please try my game?

Tags: android

I have a game on Google Play finally. I have zero budget. Can you please try it and tell me what you think? Thank you.

[Link removed by moderator]

Comment: I think this is offtopic on this site. You might try reddit or other webpages dedicated to user submits

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking us to test a game is not within the scope of the site.

Comment: I'm going to assume good intent on this post & welcome you to GDSE. SE guidelines recommend that unsolicited posts promoting a product get [flagged as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/228147). This in turn can hinder your ability to participate in & benefit from the site. You can [read here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn more about what is & isn't considered an okay here to avoid further misunderstandings. If you have a on-topic question, the community is here to help. Congratulations on shipping & good luck with your game!